# An iPhone with an ICCID printed at the box is carrier locked?

Tags: iphone

I am trying to buy an iPhone 7, but when the seller sent me photos of the box, it had a ICCID (SIM card number) number printed on it, along with IMEI, Serial number and part number.

All other iPhones I ever saw have no ICCID on the box.

Does this mean this iPhone is tied to a carrier?